# Spring Tool Suite not completing sources and javadoc download

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I have STS 4.11.1.RELEASE installed.

On the bottom right corner there's this message that keeps blinking and never stops:

"Download sources and javadoc: (66%)"

The message has been there for days.

Have restarted STS and the computer several times and that blinking message keeps there.

For some reason the download is not completing.

Have already added SpringToolSuite4.exe to the Windows Defender (which is the antivirus/firewall I'm using) allowed files list.

Have also tried completely turning off Windows Defender with no result as well.

Comment: Typically Maven or Gradle is downloading the sources and javadoc, so I think it is not related to STS.

Comment: To investigate this further, you could try to run the Maven build locally from the command line to see if that works in general. If that works, you could capture a thread dump of the running IDE process (using jps and jstack) and make that available, it might reveal where this task of downloading the sources and javadoc of the dependencies is stuck. I guess that doing a "Maven -> Update Project..." on your project works form inside of the IDE, right?

Comment: @Martin Lippert Yes "Maven > Update Project" is working now. It was not working before. But then I changed "Window > Preferences > General > Network Connections" to "manual" and it worked. After that got fixed is when the "Download sources and javadoc: (66%)" started to happen. Running a maven build from cmd also works. It outputs some debug/info message, downloads files and then a "Build Success" msg at the end, gerating the .jar file in the \target folder. Don't know how to use jps/jstack. Appreciate if you have pointers for that. Thanks.

Comment: If the IDE is still stuck at downloading sources and javadoc, I would recommend to shutdown the IDE, delete the local Maven repo (~/.m2/repository), open the IDE again, and do a Maven -> Update Project again. That should trigger the download of all the dependencies again, hopefully including the sources and javadoc.

Comment: @Martin Lippert I removed  (~/.m2/repository) and ran update project like you suggested. It executed several dowloads and then stopped. Now the blinking sources/javadoc message is indeed not there anymore. But I'm not sure that it did download the sources and javadoc to completion (or if it even started). How can I check that? Thanks.

Comment: Open a type of one of the libraries that you have as a dependency on your project. If you see source code, then the source code for that library got downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Martin seems to be right. The problem seems to be caused by a corrupted local Maven artefact stored on your hard drive in the Maven cache.

Steps to fix are just to refresh your Maven cache by removing the repository directory.

1. Close eclipse (This step is required more on Windows due to file locking).
2. Delete your `~/.m2/repository/` directory (On Windows it's under `C:\Users\<your user>\.m2\repository\`).
3. Open eclipse.

If you want to backup the cache by moving it instead of deleting then use this:

```sh
# To clear the Maven (m2) cache:
mv -v ~/.m2/repository{,_bak}

# To restore if required:
mv -v ~/.m2/repository{_bak,}

# To delete the backup once you're sure you don't need it:
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository_bak
```

Once eclipse is launched it will re-download the Maven dependencies of all your projects from scratch into a new `~/.m2/repository/` directory. This may take some time depending on the number of dependencies and your internet speed. You can see the progress of the downloads in the progress pane.

Once it's done the progress pane should no longer repeatedly show "Download sources and javadoc".

Comment: This one fixed my issue. Same issue described in the question. My issue started happening when i updated STS.